# PHP rss feed | I want only want four announcements displayed at a time

Tags: php, rss

Below is my current code:

```
<?php 
                        $feed_url = '<link removed>'; 
                        $xml_data = simplexml_load_file($feed_url);

                        $i=0; 
                        foreach($xml_data->channel->item as $ritem) { 

                        $e_title       = (string)$ritem->title; 
                        $e_link        = (string)$ritem->link; 
                        $e_pubDate     = (string)$ritem->pubDate; 
                        $e_author      = (string)$ritem->author;
                        $e_content     = $ritem->children("content", true);
                        $e_encoded     = (string)$e_content->encoded; 
                        $description   = substr($e_encoded, 0, 350).'<a style="font-weight: bold;" href="' . $e_link . '"> ...Read More</a>';

                        $n = ($i+1);
                        print "\n"; 
                        print '<h5 class="font-accident-one-bold hovercolor uppercase" style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><a href="' . $e_link . '">'. $e_title .'</a></h2>'."\n"; 
                        print '<p class="date" style="margin: 0px;">'. str_replace('+0000', '', $e_pubDate) .'</p>'."\n"; 
                        print '<p style="margin: 0px;"> <strong>By '. str_replace('invalid@example.com', '', $e_author) .'</strong></p>'."\n"; 
                        print '<p class="small" style="margin-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">'. $description .'</p>'."\n"; 

                        $i++; 
                        }
```

I'm pulling the RSS feed from my xenforo forum. I want to only display four posts at a time because, of course, it will become too much for my page if there are several posts viewable. I want it to show the newest four posts only.

Comment: Okay? then sort the array by newest and either change the `foreach` to break / stop after running 4 times or change it to a `for` loop.

Comment: I'm pretty much a noob at PHP so if you were to put some example code out there for me that'd be appreciated.

Comment: No, `foreach` and `for` loops are also pretty basic, and it's simply a matter of counting to 4 and then stopping the loop, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid break

```
$counter = 4;

for(x=0; x= $counter; x++)
{

//do something
//make sure you dont pull same data four times. But try to fetch data one by one. So this loop works for you as this loop makes four rounds
}
```

Or use continue.

Compare somedata you have like this :

```
 if($product_category>4) continue;
```

It will skip the control of the loop and go ahead

Comment: Don't use return to end loops, use [break;](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

Comment: Unfortunately, after adding that, because of how my page is setup adding a break makes my preloader "break", it won't stop showing my gif image.

Comment: Ok try using for loop instead of foreach. So you dont need break anymore. Also in for loop keep the count of $i. I will update the solution

Comment: Well whoever minused my question, thanks for making me wait another two days to ask a question when I'm here to try to learn something.